# Erro compilar robocode

Tags: java

Boa tarde!

Estou tendo problemas ao compilar o Robo de exemplo no Robocode, onde é apresentado o erro abaixo:

> Compiling... Unable to load annotation processing manager
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BatchAnnotationProcessorManager
>   from classpath.
>
> Compile Failed (-1)

Muito obrigado.

Comment: E cadê o código que gera esse erro? Clique em EDITAR e adicione ele a pergunta.]

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro acontece mesmo com o código 100% funcional.

Para resolver, vá em

> Source Editor > Compiler > Options > Preferences

A opção do meio, "**Compiler Options**" possui diversos atributos, pode apagar todos sem dó, neles estão vários atributos que só funcionariam se o código estiver dentro do eclipse, o que não é o caso.

No lugar coloque apenas o texto (com o traço antes):

```
-verbose
```

[image: imagem de exemplo]